# cannot convert lambda expression to type ienumerable because it is not a delegate type in kendo grid mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to bind dropdown in kendo grid MVC but it's giving me the error

> cannot convert lambda expression to type ienumerable because it is not
> a delegate type

Below is my code

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<mymodel.TableRelationShip>()
.Name("myid").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "table-responsive grid-table" })
.Columns(columns =>
{
   
        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.PK_User_Table, ds=>ds.Read(r => r.Action("User_Table", "PageManagement")), "PK_User_Table", "TableName")
        .Title("Primary Table").Width(200);

    columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(150);
})
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
{
    toolbar.Create();
    toolbar.Save();
})
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).CreateAt(GridInsertRowPosition.Bottom))
.Pageable()
.Navigatable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Batch(true)
    .PageSize(20)
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(p => p.PKID);
        model.Field(p => p.PKID).Editable(false);
        model.Field(p => p.PK_User_Table).DefaultValue(1);

    })
    .Create(Create => Create.Action("xyz", "mycontroller").Data("additionalInfo"))
    .Read("xyz", "mycontroller")
    .Update("xyz", "mycontroller")
    .Destroy("xyz", "mycontroller")
)
            )
```

Comment: Facing same issue

Comment: What does your additionalInfo function look like? Does your kendo grid reach the controller (you could this by putting a breakpoint in the read action? If so it might be helpful to see what the controller is like.

I'm not very familiar with the columns.ForeignKey part, if you change this to a column.bound with just one field does that at least work? If so then you've likely pinpointed your issue area at least. If that doesn't do the trick, comment out as much as possible of the code till it works, then add back in each line at a time to find where your issue is.